# This application will read the mailbox data (mbox.txt) and count the number of email messages per organization

Tags: python, sqlite

This application will read the mailbox data (mbox.txt) and count the number of email messages per organization (i.e. domain name of the email address) using a database with the following schema to maintain the counts.

`CREATE TABLE Counts (org TEXT, count INTEGER)`

I wrote a code that works, but they gave a hint in the assignment that is The top organizational count is `536`, and I got `390`.

[Link to the data](https://www.py4e.com/code3/mbox.txt?PHPSESSID=22a15d629cd11b84b13155923d49f2dc)

```py
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('data2.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Counts')
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE Counts (org TEXT,  count INTEGER)')

for line in open('mbox.txt'):
    
    if not line.startswith('From'):
        continue
    
    line = line.split()
    email = line[1]
    domaine = email.split('@')[1]    
    
    cur.execute('SELECT count FROM Counts WHERE org = ?',(email,))
    row = cur.fetchone()
    
    if not row:
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO Counts `(`org, count`) `VALUES (?,1)',(email,))

    else:
        cur.execute('UPDATE Counts SET count=count+1 WHERE org=?', (email,))

    conn.commit()
```

Comment: You are forgetting that every messages has TWO lines that start with `From`: the mbox separator, and the `From:` line from the headers.  If you just want the separator, then you need `.startswith('From '):` with an extra space.

Answer (score 0):

```json
{'iupui.edu': 536,
 'umich.edu': 491,
 'indiana.edu': 178,
 'caret.cam.ac.uk': 157,
 'vt.edu': 110,
 'uct.ac.za': 96,
 'media.berkeley.edu': 56,
 'ufp.pt': 28,
 'gmail.com': 25,
 'et.gatech.edu': 17,
 'txstate.edu': 17,
 'whitman.edu': 17,
 'lancaster.ac.uk': 14,
 'bu.edu': 14,
 'stanford.edu': 12,
 'unicon.net': 9,
 'loi.nl': 9,
 'rsmart.com': 8,
 'ucdavis.edu': 1,
 'fhda.edu': 1,
 'utoronto.ca': 1}
```

this is the dict I got from this code.  536 is the top.

```py
from pprint import pp

emails = {}
with open('mbox.txt') as file:
    while (line := file.readline()):
        if not (line.startswith('From ') and '@' in line): continue
        domain = line.split('@')[-1].split()[0]
        emails[domain] = emails.get(domain, 0) + 1

pp(dict(sorted(emails.items(), key=lambda x: -x[1])))
```

this is the dict I get with your code, so I think the filtering is suspect.

```json
{'iupui.edu': 1072,
 'umich.edu': 982,
 'indiana.edu': 356,
 'caret.cam.ac.uk': 314,
 'vt.edu': 220,
 'uct.ac.za': 192,
 'media.berkeley.edu': 112,
 'ufp.pt': 56,
 'gmail.com': 50,
 'et.gatech.edu': 34,
 'txstate.edu': 34,
 'whitman.edu': 34,
 'lancaster.ac.uk': 28,
 'bu.edu': 28,
 'stanford.edu': 24,
 'unicon.net': 18,
 'loi.nl': 18,
 'rsmart.com': 16,
 'ucdavis.edu': 2,
 'fhda.edu': 2,
 'utoronto.ca': 2}
```

Comment: can you please explain a little bit more

Answer (score 0):

import sqlite3

conn=sqlite3.connect('data2.sqlite')
cur=conn.cursor()

cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Counts')

cur.execute('CREATE TABLE Counts (org TEXT,  count INTEGER)')

fhandle=open('mbox.txt')
for line in fhandle:
if not line.startswith('From: ')  : continue

```
line=line.split()
email=line[1]
domaine=email.split('@')
domaine=domaine[1]

cur.execute('SELECT count FROM Counts WHERE org= ?',(domaine,))
row=cur.fetchone()
if row is None :
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO Counts (org,count) VALUES (?,1)',(domaine,))
else:
    cur.execute('UPDATE Counts SET count=count+1 WHERE org=?',(domaine,))
    
    
conn.commit()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).